# Express doesn't serve all static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
// router.js
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')));
router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html'));
});

// server.js
app.use('/', router);
```

The problem is, that several needed files are in the directory but express doesn't serve them and sends 304 status. 
There are no problem with minified javascript or css, only with images and .tag files.

Comment: 304 means files are cached and being served properly

Comment: @ankitbug94 Reviewed sources in Chrome devtools and found need files in "no domain" tab. Are there any ways to access them in html?

Comment: Not familiar with chrometools this much as I use morgan as a logger with expressJS. And what do you mean by access in HTML? If you can open those files directly in browser then they will be inserted in HTML

Comment: @ankitbug94 Reviewed code and found that problem wasn't in server-code. Thanks a lot!